# Super Script and Hyphenation Problems

Tags: luatex, koma-script, typography, hyphenation, superscripts

I am using `LuaLaTeX` compiler with `KOMA-scrbook` class.

I need to define a command with superscript text, but I do not know why LaTeX disable the hyphenation of words with superscript text.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0.1cm}{
  advanced, however}

\parbox{0.1cm}{
  advanced,\textsuperscript{1} however\textsuperscript{2}, maybe\textsuperscript{†}}




\end{document}
```

Why the words "advanced" and "however" do not have hyphenation when used with `\textsuperscript`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\textsuperscript` is implemented using TeX's math mode, so `however\textsuperscript{1}` behaves similar to `however$abc$`. Since the inline math formula is not separated from the word and hyphenation of "words" partially consisting of mathematical expressions is not really well-defined, TeX does not try to hyphenate such constructs.

You can tell LuaTeX that the previous word ended by adding an explicit `\wordboundary`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0.1cm}{
  advanced, however}

\parbox{0.1cm}{
  advanced,\wordboundary\textsuperscript{1} however\wordboundary\textsuperscript{2}, maybe\wordboundary\textsuperscript{†}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! I just found out about the `\wordboundary` macro.

Comment: @Mico Not that it matters too much, but technically it's a primitive and not a macro.

Comment: Or applying `\leavevmode\nobreak` at the beginning of `\@textsuperscript`? OK, this might change many documents.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be to use a font which has *real* superscripts, like Libertinus, EBGaramond, Erewhon, etc., together with the `realscript` package. Then your example would work out of the box.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{realscripts} % loads fontspec
\setmainfont{erewhon}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0.1cm}{%
  advanced, however, maybe}

\parbox{0.1cm}{%
  advanced,\textsuperscript{1} however\textsuperscript{2},
  maybe\textsuperscript{†}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]